# How fast is an HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, clone, hardware-selection

Recently I have replaced my SSD drive with an HDD drive (cloned the 250GB kingstone SSD to a 1TB HDD) at first boot the PC was running at an unusable speed took about 10m to turn on ,apps took 15-30s to launch after a few reboots this process took almost half the time but still is very slow (5m to boot ,7-14s app launch time) compared to the SSD with a boot speed of about 1.5m and 2-7s app launching time . Is this Normal ? Is this a result of hardware changes ? Or will deleting the all disk and reinstalling windows should change anything?(assuming that I will reinstall most of the apps)

---

SSD: KINGSTON SV300S37A240G (240GB) 
3Years old

---

HDD: WDC WD10EFRX-68FYTNO (1000GB)
Completely New

Comment: You could trouble shoot and check on its capabilities vs real world performance, but yes, a HDD COULD run that slow. Although what you are experiencing sounds a bit slower than usual.

Comment: assuming that I have done a full disk clone to the HDD is there any chance that there is a software problem that wasn't in the SSD ?, Is it worth formatting the HDD ?

Comment: HDDs have an incredibly slow seek time compared to SSDs. During boot the disk is doing a large amount of seeking to the point that it can seem to dominate over actual data reads. Those speeds still sound like you have an unreasonable amount of stuff starting up with the computer.

Comment: @Mokubai  ok these are the times of loading the desktop only : 40s for the SSD and 2.5m for the HDD is that a reasonable different ?

Comment: Could perhaps add the exact make and model of both SSD and HDD to your question?

Comment: @DanielB Ok model of both added in edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDD is much slower then SSD and goes some way to explaining your problem.  An SSD is faster in 2 respects - the raw"sequential"  speed is in the order of 5 times as fast as hdd, but that's not as important as the latency - which is orders of magnitude faster on SSD because it's not waiting for a spinning disk.

USING A DISK DEFRAGMENTER could help a lot.

A second issue is most likely swap/paging.  I expect your system is paging more agressivrly because SSD is fast - and your system is gradually recalibrating itself to page less/differently - which could explain the gradually increase on speed from when you first switched.

THAT SAID - HDDs are a step backwards, and, in the general case can't compete with SSD in any measure other then price/gig - you might want to try going back to SSD for your not disk and using hdd for files. ( If it's a laptop this may not be practical, or you might be able to put the hdd in the CD bay if it has one, or in a USB enclosure )

It's unlikely but not impossible your hdd is faulty, and is reallocating sectors. Get a tool to look at the Schedule.M.A.R.T values of your hdd to check.

Comment: Also the HDD won't boot in RAID so I use ACHI, how bad that changes performance ?

Comment: I *very* much doubt Windows paging behavior is any different on SSDs. Even with a SSD, RAM is so much faster that any change would make the system perform worse. And even if it were different, it’s a switch, not a learning algorithm.

Comment: There's also the fact that Windows disables superfetch on SSDs and would reenable it on an HDD. This could add extra disk load and slowness right after the desktop is shown, further adding to the "time before system is useful".

Comment: The defragmenter helped a lot 3.5mins for full boot 1.5min less ... impressive

Comment: 'your not disk' -> 'your boot disk' ?